# How to enable Dict/OrderedDict/NamedTuple support in pytorch 1.1.0 JIT compiler?

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard, torchscript

From the release highlight of pytorch 1.1.0. It appears that the latest JIT compiler now supports Dict type. (Source: https://jaxenter.com/pytorch-1-1-158332.html)

> > Dictionary and list support in TorchScript: Lists and dictionary types behave like Python lists and dictionaries.

Unfortunately I can't find a way to make this improvement to work properly. The following code is a simple example of exporting a Feature Pyramid Network (FPN) into tensorboard, which uses the JIT compiler:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

import torch
import torchvision
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

torchWriter = SummaryWriter(log_dir=".tensorboard/example1")

m = torchvision.ops.FeaturePyramidNetwork([10, 20, 30], 5)
# get some dummy data
x = OrderedDict()
x['feat0'] = torch.rand(1, 10, 64, 64)
x['feat2'] = torch.rand(1, 20, 16, 16)
x['feat3'] = torch.rand(1, 30, 8, 8)
# compute the FPN on top of x
output = m.forward(x)
print([(k, v.shape) for k, v in output.items()])

torchWriter.add_graph(m, input_to_model=x)
```

When I run it I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shared/virtualenv/dl-torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/_pytorch_graph.py", line 276, in graph
    trace, _ = torch.jit.get_trace_graph(model, args)
  File "/home/shared/virtualenv/dl-torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/jit/__init__.py", line 231, in get_trace_graph
    return LegacyTracedModule(f, _force_outplace, return_inputs)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shared/virtualenv/dl-torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shared/virtualenv/dl-torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/jit/__init__.py", line 284, in forward
    in_vars, in_desc = _flatten(args)
RuntimeError: Only tuples, lists and Variables supported as JIT inputs, but got collections.OrderedDict

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peng/git-drone/gate_detection/python/gate_detection/errorcase/tb.py", line 36, in <module>
    torchWriter.add_graph(m, input_to_model=x)
  File "/home/shared/virtualenv/dl-torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/writer.py", line 534, in add_graph
    self._get_file_writer().add_graph(graph(model, input_to_model, verbose, **kwargs))
  File "/home/shared/virtualenv/dl-torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/_pytorch_graph.py", line 279, in graph
    _ = model(*args)  # don't catch, just print the error message
  File "/home/shared/virtualenv/dl-torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

From the error message it appears that the support is still pending. Can I trust the release highlight? Or I'm not using the API properly?

Answer (score 3):

The release notes are accurate albeit a little vague. The dictionary/list/user defined classes support described in that link (and the [official release notes](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v1.1.0)) only apply to the [TorchScript compiler](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html#creating-torchscript-code) (there are some code examples in the release notes), but `SummaryWriter` by default will run the TorchScript tracer on whatever module you pass to it, and the tracer only supports Tensors and lists/tuples of Tensors.

So the fix would be to use the TorchScript compiler rather than the tracer, but that requires:

1. Access to the original code
2. Support for the compiled output (`ScriptModule`) in Tensorboard

You should [file an issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues) for (2), and there is [ongoing work](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/20939) to fix (1), but this won't work in the short term for that model afaik.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying! Just to be sure: do you mean that the TorchScript tracer won't support its own compiled output (ScriptModel) in debugging? Is this supposed to be the only functionality of the tracer?